# Embedding a JavaScript File as a Resource in an Assembly in visual studio 2017

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I'm unable to add reference of angular js file location in visual studio 2017 community as I usually do in visual studio 2015

Comment: Hi Raziuddin Mohd, could you please share the detail steps that you add the JS files as a resource in an assembly? I will test it in my VS 2017 and check if the result as yours.

Comment: thanks ,its working ,but the reference line for angularJS is not auto generated when i drag and drop angular.mon.js in my .js file....But its working now without that line too.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this: [Can't drag AngularJS intellisense reference to code window](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/6435/cant-drag-angularjs-intellisense-reference-to-code.html)

Van Kichline [MSFT]: With the new JavaScript language service these references are no longer required, so they aren't written to the file.

So we can know this behavior is **by design**, which means the reference line will not auto create, we can directly invoke the contents like function inside each .js file among the whole project, you can have a try with it, this works in my VS 2017.